# Contributions of infinitesimal integrals to the total integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Consider for example the function $f(x)=x$. We know that $\int_a^a x dx = 0, \forall a\in\mathbb{R}$.  Now let's consider an arbitrary interval, say $[1,2]$. We see that $\int_1^2 x dx \ne 0$.

My observation: $$ \int_1^2f = \int_1^1f+\int_{1.000\dots 0001}^{1.000\dots 0001}f+\int_{1.000\dots 0002}^{1.000\dots 0002}f+\dots+\int_{1.999\dots 9999}^{1.999\dots 9999}f+\int_2^2f.$$

All of these smaller contributions equal $0$, but there are uncountable many of these contributions. Is there an intuitive way to understand how their sum (= the final integral) is not equal to $0$? Mathematical explanations are welcome as well.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: if you are satisfied with your answer, then please click the green check to close the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral is not a sum of uncountably many "one-point integrals", but it is the limit of finite sums of rectangle areas $f(\xi_k)(x_k-x_{k-1})$. These are ordinary rectangles $[x_{k-1},x_k]\times[0,f(\xi_k)]$ in the $(x,y)$-plane. During the limiting process we have finer and finer partitions of $[a,b]$, but all approximating figures are finite rectangle buildings of ordinary euclidean geometry.

Answer (score 0):

Every integral on the hand side of the equation is equal to $0$ and their sum is equal to $0$. Thus, both sides of your equation are NOT equivalent. The conventional definition of an integral is defined as follows:

$$\int f(x) dx = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \sum_{i=0}^n f(x_i) \mathbb{\Delta}x$$
where
$$\mathbb{\Delta}x=\frac{b-a}{n}$$
and
$[a,b]$ is the interval you are integrating over, $n$ is a finite number of partitions of the interval $[a,b]$, and although $x_i$ can be defined in several creative ways, here we have
$$x_i=a+i\mathbb{\Delta}x$$
The product of $f(x_i) \mathbb{\Delta}x$ for $i=0,1,2,...,n$ is the area of a rectangle between the curve of $f$ and the x-axis with edges in the interval $[a,b]$. The integral is effectively calculated by $(1)$ shrinking the width of each rectangle so that we can fit more rectangles between $f$ and the x-axis and $(2)$ adding up the areas of all the rectangles. Of course, if you do this for any finite number of rectangles, i.e. any finite $n$, then at best you have an approximation. But we don't want an approximation; we want an exact one, so instead we find the limiting value as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

[image]

**Conceptually, you are adding the areas of an infinite number of rectangles that have infinitely small widths. This is NOT the same as adding the areas of an infinite number of rectangles that have $0$ width, which is what you have in your equation. It's tricky to wrap one's mind around, because we are dealing with infinity. It helps to consider that as the number of rectangles increases, the area of each rectangle decreases at a specific rate so as to preserve the limiting value of the their sum.**